# How does one compile a file with an interface, in BuckleScript?

Tags: compiler-errors, ocaml, reason, bucklescript, bsb

Without `bsb`, how does one compile any more than a single unqualified `.ml` file?

```
$ touch test.ml
$ touch test.mli
$ bsc test.ml
File "test.ml", line 1:
Error: Could not find the .cmi file for interface test.mli.
```

I haven't even gotten as far as trying to do this with an `ocamlfind` library, pretty sure I'm going to want to kill myself when I get that far.

Dune [doesn't support BuckleScript](https://github.com/ocaml/dune/issues/140); `bsb` doesn't support any of the OCaml testing tools (ppx_inline_test, ppx_expect) or ppx_deriving plugins as far as I can tell … I'm at wits' end here. Help me figure out how to *actually use* BuckleScript.

Comment: Have you tried the method shown here: https://github.com/BuckleScript/bucklescript/issues/2407

Comment: “At this time, we don't really encourage people to use ppx in the wild,” — oh no.

Answer (score -3):

I did not try, but below should work.

`bsc -c test.mli test.ml`